# Error trying to use static var inside an array in another class var

Tags: php

Besides of talk a lot of not useful things, there goes my code:

```
1 public static $_INT = 'INTEGER';
2 protected $_name = 'projetos';
3 protected $_primary = 'id';
4 protected $_fields = Array (
    Array ('id', self::$_INT)
);
```

I'm having an error on line 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self::$_INT` is an expression, you cannot use an expression in the declaration of a property in a class, you can only use static values.

You will have to initialise `$_fields` in the constructor if you want to do this.

Like

```
class MyClass {

  public static $_INT = 'INTEGER';
  protected $_name = 'projetos';
  protected $_primary = 'id';
  protected $_fields;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->fields = Array (
      Array ('id', self::$_INT)
    );
  }

}
```